# how to insert record in between particular record in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor

suppose i have a customer balance details table. For Example :

```
CustID    CustName  CustDate    Amt   Bal
1          DP       1/5/2013   1000  1000
1          DP       5/5/2013   100   1100
1          Dhara    10/5/2013  1000  1000
1          DP       10/5/2013  1000  2100
```

now user insert a record CustName = DP , CustDate = 7/5/2013 , Amt = 400 then that record should be added after date 5/5/2013 and before 10/5/2013 and respective balance should be change also as follows :

```
CustID    CustName  CustDate    Amt   Bal
1          DP       1/5/2013   1000  1000
1          DP       5/5/2013   100   1100
1          DP       7/5/2013   400   1500
1          Dhara    10/5/2013  1000  1000
1          DP       10/5/2013  1000  2500
```

How do i achieve when inserting record in database ? How do i check when date lies between already inserted records ? Please Help

Comment: The location of the data is probably the least of your concerns. It's almost always a question of how you retrieve it. You have lots of sorting options when retrieving data from the table.

Comment: SQL Server tables don't have any order, really - you just add your rows at the end of it, and when you need your rows in a particular order, you have to ask for it by using `ORDER BY` anyway....

Comment: any specific example ?

Comment: how can we generate new column and sum up Amt in BAL ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can get what you want if you use an ORDER BY clause to access the data in the desired order. Please also refer to your DB documentation for the use of indices.

Comment: The balance value can be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one suggestion on how do do it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d341b/9

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
  CustId INT,
  CustName NVARCHAR(150),
  CustDate DATE,
  Amt INT,
)

INSERT INTO Customer
    (CustID, CustName, CustDate, Amt)
VALUES
    (1, 'DP', '2013-01-05 00:00:00', 1000),
    (1, 'DP', '2013-05-05 00:00:00', 100),
    (1, 'DP', '2013-07-05 00:00:00', 400),
    (1, 'Dhara', '2013-10-05 00:00:00', 1000),
    (1, 'DP', '2013-10-05 00:00:00', 1000)
;

;WITH RankedCustomer AS
(
  SELECT
    CustId
    , CustName
    , CustDate
    , Amt
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CustDate) Row
  FROM
    Customer
)
SELECT
  Customer.CustId
  , Customer.CustName
  , Customer.CustDate
  , Customer.Amt
  , SUM(PreviousCustomer.Amt)
FROM
  RankedCustomer Customer
  LEFT JOIN RankedCustomer PreviousCustomer
    ON PreviousCustomer.CustId = Customer.CustId
    AND PreviousCustomer.CustName = Customer.CustName
    AND PreviousCustomer.Row <= Customer.Row
GROUP BY
  Customer.CustId
  , Customer.CustName
  , Customer.CustDate
  , Customer.Amt
ORDER BY
  Customer.CustDate
```